# Modifying Arrays Between Files and Functions in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a Sudoku Solver. I am also trying to create small files for each task so that I don't have an impossibly large file to debug. Ignoring the input, I need to take the 9x9 matrix and split it into 9 arrays of 9 values. I would like to do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int Matrix[9][9] = {
        [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,0,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,0,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,0,7,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,9],
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0]
        };

    int Row[9] = SplitMatrix(Matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

with SplitMatrix looking like:

```
int Array[9];

int SplitMatrix(int Matrix[][])    
{
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            Array[j] = Matrix[i][j];
        }

        return Array;
    }
}
```

The errors I keep running into are either type errors (int vs int*), assignability errors of course, and just a failure to send/receive the correct data.

My main problems are:

(1) Arrays aren't assignable, so how do I take the return from a function and make it into an array to pass on later?

(2) Arrays when sent to functions decompose into (pseudo-)pointers, so how do I send and receive the entire array data between files/functions, not just the address of the first index?

(3) Once I go to solve for the blank space in each row [aka the 0], I only end up modifying the local array, especially when I have to use for loops, so whether it's pass by reference or pass by value (I don't really care which) how do I make sure that any modifications I do within a file/function get back to the place that called it?

(4) Is there a way to use looping to generate 9 arrays with one command/function call? Or do I need to make 9 discrete arrays and call the function 9 times, passing a row number each time?

- I've tried using pointers and addresses, but I keep getting type errors.
- I've tried passing the arrays themselves, but they decompose into pointers that don't quite work like pointers (though my knowledge on pointers isn't super solid, admittedly).
- I've tried chasing warnings and errors, but the data doesn't behave the way it should (scope issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To treat an array as a copy assignable variable, you can wrap the array in a struct:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int items[9];
} Row;

typedef struct {
  Row rows[9];
} Matrix;

int main() {
  Matrix a = {{
    {0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    {1,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    {1,2,0,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    {1,2,3,0,5,6,7,8,9},
    {1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9},
    {1,2,3,4,5,0,7,8,9},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,9},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,9},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0},
  }};

  // Structs allow copy assignment
  Matrix b = a;
  
  printf("matrix: %d\n", b.rows[1].items[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

C++ would allow for nicer syntax than `b.rows[1].items[1]`. To modify the `Matrix` or `Row` in a function pass it in as `Matrix*` or `Row*`. To answer your last question, you can also return structs from a function so you could return `Row`s from a generator function.

Comment: It is definitely nota good way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *SplitMatrix(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*Matrix)[cols])
{
    int *Array = malloc(rows * sizeof(*Array));
    if(Array)
        for (size_t i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            for (size_t j=0; j<cols; j++)
            {
                 Array[j] = Matrix[i][j];
            }
    }
    return Array;
}
```

```
/* .... */
int *Row = SplitMatrix(Matrix);
/* some code */
free(Row);
```

1. You need to return **pointer to `int`** not `int`.
2. The computer has to know how big your matrix is.
3. use the correct type for indexes